# how do you directly call a python main function utilizing optparse?

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

folks, i inherited a python script main using optParse to construct a menu of items for the user to pick through:

```
def main():
    
    parser = optParse(prog='script')
    #parser.add_option("-e","--repeat",dest="repeat",type=int,default=3,help="Total number of times to do the checking.")
    parser.add_option("-H","--time",dest="time", type='float', default=1.0,help="Time in hours to run the test.")
```

what need to do is to call this main function from within a **running** python session, but don't quite know how to specify the parameters.  something similar to this:

```
import script
script.main(['-e', '5', '-H', '2'])
```

however, the main function has no input parameters as it is.  What is the easiest way to modify main to accomplish passing parameters in the manner specified?

Comment: You would have to modify `sys.args` to simulate the command line you want.  Can you not just call the functions that would call?

Comment: Your parser needs a `parse_args` call, which from the docs looks like: `(options, args) = parser.parse_args(args=None, values=None)`; `args` can be a list of strings.  If it is `None`, it will use `sys.argv[1:]`.  Sometimes the `main` is defined as `def main(argv=None): ...`, pass the `argv` to `parse_args`.  Then the `main` caller can either use `main()`, or `main(['-e','5'...])`

Answer (score 1):

Your parser needs a `parse_args` call, which from the docs looks like:

```
(options, args) = parser.parse_args(args=None, values=None)
```

`args` can be a list of strings. If it is `None`, it will use `sys.argv[1:]`.

Sometimes the main is defined as

```
def main(argv=None): 
    parser = ...
    ...
    options, args = parser.parse_args(argv)
```

Then the main caller can either use

```
 main()    # or
 main(['-e','5'...])
```

Answer (score 0):

from the answer from Tim Roberts, the following works:

```
def main():
    parser = optParse(prog='script')
    #parser.add_option("-e","--repeat",dest="repeat",type=int,default=3,help="Total number of times to do the checking.")
    parser.add_option("-H","--time",dest="time", type='float', default=1.0,help="Time in hours to run the test.")
    sys.argv = ['scripyt.py', '-e', '5', '-H', '2']
```

then just calling the following from the running python session:

```
script.main()
```

Comment: This needs something equivalent to `argparse's` `parse_args`